# VBA copying a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code. Please help!

I am trying to copy a discontinuous range of cells.

```
Sub ()
 
Worksheets("Name").Activate
 
Dim Rng1 As Range
Set Rng1 = Range("B24:K24")
Dim Rng2 As Range
Set Rng2 = Rng1.End(xlDown)
Dim Rng3 As Range
Set Rng3 = Union(Range("C9"), Range("C11"), Range("C13"), Range("C15"), Rng2)
 
Rng3.Copy
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that you can't do this manually ("This action won't work on multiple selections"), so you won't be able to do it with VBA either as written.

Comment: It will work if your union range is in the same row or column - if you were to remove `Rng2` from your union it would work as the other references are all in column C.  Also `Rng1.End(xlDown)` will return the reference to column B only (manually select B24:K24 and then press Ctrl+Down and it will select the last cell in the first column of your selection).  Also - if `B24:K24` is only a single row of data then xlDown will go to the bottom of the sheet.

Comment: Where do you plan to paste these cells? In the same arrangement on another sheet, or clustered together as a continuous range/column?